# How can analyze the diffuse texture and normal texture from obj with a mtl , by using python

Tags: image

I want to analyze the diffuse texture image and normal texture image from obj by using blender python api.
So I tried

```
import bpy
bpy.ops.import_scene.obj(filepath="Kake.obj")
objects = bpy.data.objects
for object in objects:
    for s in object.material_slots:
        if s.material and s.material.use_nodes:
            for n in s.material.node_tree.nodes:
                if n.type == 'TEX_IMAGE':
                    print(object.name, 'uses', n.image.name, 'saved at', n.image.filepath,n.color_space)
```

And the mtl like this

```
newmtl CL_LR_Baked1
    map_Kd CL_LR_01DiffuseMap.jpg
    map_bump CL_LR_01NormalsMap.jpg
newmtl 03___Default
    map_Kd CL_LR_02DiffuseMap.jpg
    map_bump CL_LR_02NormalsMap.jpg
```

But I found I can't know which node is diffuse and which node is normal.Because their name  is "Image Texture","Image Texture.001" . Is there any way to help?

Answer (score 1):

I solve it by material.node_tree.links.

```
for object in objects:
    for s in object.material_slots:
        if s.material and s.material.use_nodes:
            for link in s.material.node_tree.links:
                if link.to_node.name == "Principled BSDF" and link.to_socket.identifier == "Base Color":
                    if link.from_node.type == 'TEX_IMAGE':
                        print(s.material.name, "diffuse",link.from_node.image.filepath)
                if link.to_node.name == "Normal Map" and link.to_socket.identifier == "Color":
                    if link.from_node.type == 'TEX_IMAGE':
                        print(s.material.name, "normal", link.from_node.image.filepath)
```